# Enumerate SCOM monitoring objects for machine

Tags: c#, scom

How do I enumerate all monitoring objects on a machine?
Today I'm trying to query ManagementPacks that I know should be there. It is inconvenient especially in cases when packs added.

This is what I'm doing today:
Get the pack and a class

```
var pack = mg.ManagementPacks.GetManagementPack("Microsoft.Windows.Library", "31bf3856ad364e35", new Version(1, 0, 0, 0));
var managementClass = mg.EntityTypes.GetClass("Microsoft.Windows.Computer", pack);
```

Create a query to get all objects

```
EnterpriseManagementObjectCriteria machineCriteria = new EnterpriseManagementObjectCriteria("DisplayName like '%" + machineName + "%'", managementClass);
```

Get monitor objects

```
mg.EntityObjects.GetObjectReader<MonitoringObject>(machineCriteria, ObjectQueryOptions.Default)
```

Not most convenient way - I have to know the pack name and the class name.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you to write a stored procedure on database. 
Or create custom database for you purposes & set up daily update from SCOM DWH base to it.
Object parent-child relations easily accessible in DB, but in the microsoft scom library... I can't say a lot of good things about it.

Comment: Do you mean read directly from SCOM tables?  Is there a documentation anywhere about how to do that?

Comment: apart of Kevin Holman's blog... I don't think so. But you definitely should consider checking out Squared UP  [link](https://squaredup.com/)